# CopyFromScreen with different behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a button to capture the screenshot of the RichTextBox.

So I took the answer from this page : [how-to-save-the-content-of-richtextbox-as-jpg-file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1454d078-c312-4741-88df-aa7eb306fe51/how-to-save-the-content-of-richtextbox-as-jpg-file?forum=winforms)

And it mention that

> This ought to work well, as long as no other window overlaps your RTB.

But is't not always happen

here is my code :

```
class ScreenCapture
{
    public static void Capture(RichTextBox rtb, string filename)
    {
        rtb.Update();  // Ensure RTB fully painted
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rtb.Width, rtb.Height);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gr.CopyFromScreen(rtb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, rtb.Size);
        }
        bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And in my Form :

```
partial class Form1
{
    private void Btn_Screenshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = saveScreenshotDialog.ShowDialog();
        var fileName = saveScreenshotDialog.FileName;
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ScreenCapture.Capture(this.rtb_Result, fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

As the code above, I use a `saveFileDialog` to let the user decide where to save the JPG file

In some machine, the `CopyFromScreen` will capture the img of `saveFileDialog` window while some don't. On my windows 10, the CopyFromScreen works perfectly, but on my colleague's machine, the output JPG file always contains the img of saveFileDialog window. Which means the saveFileDialog window block the RTB, caused the CopyFromScreen capture the saveFileDialog window instead of RTB

**here's the question :**

What cause the different behavior?(capture the img of `saveFileDialog` window or not)

Why this happen, since the `CopyFromScreen` was triggered after the `saveFileDialog` window closed.
There is no reason that `CopyFromScreen` capture the img of `saveFileDialog` window

Comment: On the machines where it doesn't work, what results do you get?

Comment: @John On my windows 10 , the CopyFromScreen  works perfectly, but on my colleague's machine, the output JPG file always contains the img of saveFileDialog window. Which means the saveFileDialog window block the RTB,caused the CopyFromScreen  capture the saveFileDialog window instead of RTB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a timing issue. You're (likely) capturing the *screen* before the save dialog closes fully. I think the simplest solution might be as follows:

1. Capture the image.
2. Show the save dialog.
3. Save the image.

Expressed as code:

```
private void Btn_Screenshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var bmp = ScreenCapture.Capture(this.rtb_Result))
    {
        var result = saveScreenshotDialog.ShowDialog();
        var fileName = saveScreenshotDialog.FileName;
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ScreenCapture.Save(bmp, fileName);
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap Capture(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    rtb.Update();  // Ensure RTB fully painted
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rtb.Width, rtb.Height);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gr.CopyFromScreen(rtb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, rtb.Size);
    }
    return bmp;
}

public static void Save(Bitmap bmp, string filename)
{
    bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: I just test your code, and it works fine. Thanks a lot.